# Extra details in output of c++ using g++

Tags: c++

i have made a program in c++ , there is no compilation error and it runs fine but at the end of the output it alwas shows my device name and directory in the same line. i have tried using endl but still no change(i am using g++)
the program code is as follows

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int  max(int *,int); 
int main()
{int n,a[10],b;
 cout<<"Please enter the no. of integers you wish to enter ";
 cin>>n;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {cout<<endl<<"please enter the "<<i+1<<" no. ";
  cin>>a[i];
 }
 b=max(a,n);
 cout<<endl<<"The greatest no. is "<<a[b]<<" and its index position is "<<b<<endl;
 return 0;
}
int max(int *ptr,int n)
{int i,max,k=0;
 max=ptr[0];
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {if(max<ptr[i])
  {max=ptr[i];
   k=i;
  }
 }
 return k;
}
```

and the output
Please enter the no. of integers you wish to enter 4

please enter the 1 no. 2

please enter the 2 no. 4

please enter the 3 no. 6

please enter the 4 no. 1

The greatest no. is 6 and its index position is 2**himanshu@hunt:~/Documents/Himanshu/C++$**

Comment: Show us your code for the output line

Comment: The problem will certainly be that you are misusing endl. Please post some code.

Comment: redirect the output to a file and you will be sure what it is

Comment: Check your shell prompt (PS1). BTW: whitespace doesn't slow down execution. Lack of it slows down comprehension among human readers. Don't fear the space and return keys.

Comment: i am new to g++ and ubuntu ,earlier i was using turboc++ and it had nothing of this sort ,i just want to know if i there is something wrong with the program i have entered and if not then why isnt endl that i have placed at the end work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the info you have given, it seems that no new line is being printed on the end of the output, that means the either you forgot to recompile when you added `std::endl`, or you have misplaced it.

**Edit:**
I just ran your code the way you posted it. The `endl` worked correctly, and the command line was placed below the output of your code. You are clearly running an old binary, from when the code didn't had the `endl` yet. Look carefully in your `g++` invocation the name of the generated file (the name after `-o`), and where it is being placed. You may try to rename the executable file you are running to something else, and run `g++` to see if a new file is generated with the name you are expecting.

Comment: i have re-compiled it, the device name and the directory that is being printed right after the output is just as if i have pressed enter in the terminal but it is still on the same line

Comment: By "as if i have pressed enter" you mean, the empty command prompt? The one that reappears every time you press `<enter>` without inputting any command?

Comment: So, it is what I said in my edit, the problem is external to your code. As I said, I have tested it myself and it worked, you are probably not running the binary corresponding to the code.

Comment: as i said earlies i am new to ubuntu and g++ i dont understand what you really are trying to tell me to try, i have changed the output file name by using g++ -o ...... and i recently installed g++ (in fact this week only ) and my ubuntu 12.10 is completely updated

Comment: (regarding binary code) if it helps i downloaded g++ and its multilib files

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned earlier, make sure you have the `using namespace std` and `#include <iostream>` in your code.